# Boot up HTPC with input from game controller?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, game-controller

How can I do this?

I've found some powershell commands online that list usb devices and another that should allow me to force one to allow waking from a device.

powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any

powercfg -deviceenablewake "deviceID"

but when I do the device query I get a whole lot of devices turning up and none of them have names that mention anything controller related. I'm pretty sure its loading in as some sort of HID compliant device on the list.

What I'm hoping is that someone has made a script or program to map USB devices as bootable usb devices, but I've been unable to find one searching github. I feel like my searches are getting clogged up in osx drivers and stopping windows from waking when a usb devices is used.

So any suggestions?

Comment: Waking or booting? In my mind, "waking" is waking from sleep, i.e. the machine is on, just in sleep mode. "Booting" is cold-booting, i.e. the machine is off and you wish to turn it on.

Comment: Both. I want it to wake up from being shut off and also from being asleep. I've enabled all my wake from usb related settings in my bios and just need to make Windows cooperate.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to cold boot a PC by pressing a button on a USB input device. It should be possible to wake a PC from sleep, though.

Comment: i've only seen this for keyboards, and that depends on the bios or a proprietary supporting circuit on something like a laptop mobo that can monitor the kb in a low-power fashion; the atx spec itself doesn't lend this capability.

Answer (score 0):

This partially depends on your motherboard BIOS/UEFI firmware and if it supports power on using keyboard/other device. You cannot reliably trust that any system board can supports anything like this.

If I were you and if you like to do a DYI project I would use a Raspberry PI or Arduino to control a switch in parallel with your case power button to "press" the power button to short the pins, causing the system to power on. You can have a RF or even IR sensor to send the signal to your Arduino (or what about an app to do it via your smart phone over Wifi or network to your Raspberry Pi if you really want to get fancy).

If you build this device right then it can guarantee that it will work with any PC you have/build with a little harmless hardware hack.

Comment: I like the idea but I think for a weekend project I might try to get it working software side first. Even if that doesnt work I'm pretty sure I could set my home server up to magic packet to the powered down pc if I can figure out a way to trigger that with a bluetooth controller. Unraids pretty flexible I could probably work out a docker or something. Still plan A I think will be to code a UWP app that can set devices as bootable usb devices on compatible motherboards. I feel like this should be doable from what I've read, apparently MS disabled this functionality of USB devices in 2018.